Local convexity and $\lim_{s\rightarrow t} \frac{|\gamma(s)-\gamma(t)|}{L(\gamma|_{[t,s]})}$
I have to prove the following lemma: Let
$\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a locally convex curve with constant speed $C$. Then
one sided derivatives of $\gamma$
exists at all points and it holds $|\gamma'(t)|=C$ in all differentiable points (I mean one-sided derivatives). While I understand most of the proof, I struggle understanding the following claim that results (according to the authors) from local convexity:
$\lim_{s\rightarrow t} \frac{|\gamma(s)-\gamma(t)|}{L(\gamma|_{[t,s]})}=1$ if $t$ is a differentiable point (and to be exact: one-sided Limites are taken).
Note: $\gamma$ is said to be locally convex, if it locally lies on the boundary of a convex body in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Thanks for your help in advance!
